# How to properly use CI scripts with Git hooks to compress source

Tags: git, build, continuous-integration, branch, githooks

I have a `feature` branch and a `testing` branch (for initial regression).  I would like to have a working copy available for my `testing` branch for the testing environment.  However, I need to compress some of the source code (not into binary, just optimize) via a script.  I can enact this script via a post-receive Git hook.

I'm trying to design my bash script (for CI) so that it's fairly robust and want to avoid automation causing Git conflicts.  I'm thinking of having a main repository (`origin`) and a testing environment repository (`ci_test`) simply to allow CI to commit.

I'm thinking about pushing to `ci_test/testing` when promoting source.  CI should compress, add, commit, fetch from `origin/testing`, merge if necessary (taking theirs-full iff conflicts), then push to `origin/testing`.

The problem to my model above is that Git complains when I attempt to push to `ci_test/testing` because it has a working copy (makes sense, because they may not be synced).  Is there a proper (automated) way to use Continuous Integration scripts with Git so that they're still tracked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem to my model above is that Git complains when I attempt to push to `ci_test/testing` because it has a working copy (makes sense, because they may not be synced).

You can either:

- make sure your `ci_test` is a bare repo, with a [`post-receive` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) which would:

  - [checkout your branch `testing`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41583600/6309)
  - triggers all your operations
- or, if you are the only one pushing to that `ci_testing` remote repo, configure the remote Git to accept pushes to a non-bare repo.
  This is possible [since Git 2.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28262104/6309) with:

  ```
  git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead
  ```

And [with Git 2.4+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34575157/6309), you can setup the remote `ci_testing` with a "`push-to-checkout`" hook, which can be installed on the server to customize exactly what happens when a user pushes to the checked-out branch.

Comment: [Push-to-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_push_to_checkout) hook looks promising.  I wasn't aware of that hook existing.

The reason I wanted ci_test to have a working copy is because the hook would modify source and I want to commit changes (I can't imagine being able to do that without a working copy).  I'm also using the working copy as the directory that is used to read the testing version of the application.

Comment: @BLaZuRE yes, in your case, push-to-checkout seems a good fit.