# Add git repository to existing folder on VSP

Tags: git, gitlab, push, git-bare

My Setup looks like this:

**Bare Repo** in my Root `/srv` Folder

**Local Repo** on my PC

**Gitlab Repo** on *well* Gitlab

I added two origins (Gitlab and my Bare Repo) to push all changes from my local machine to the source.
Now I want to set up a post-receive Hook in my **Bare Repo** so it will update the working directory on my VSP (where the **Bare Repo lies**)

But I already developed before without git (all the files are the same), I don´t want to clone the Repo in another directory, but just add the `.git` Folder to my `var/www/project`.
Is that possible with git?
Or is there no clean way around cloning the Repo and change folders?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to do with the two remotes. What do you need - multiple workspaces/working-copies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don´t want to clone the Repo in annother directory, but just add the .git Folder to my var/www/project

Usually, you use the [`post-receive` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) set in the bare repo to checkout said repo into the destination folder:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/project_root/.git --work-tree=/var/www/project/ checkout -f
```

Comment: I also have this configuration on annother project, is there no .git folder necessary to checkout those changes to my production/live system? (/var/www/project/)

Comment: @Isengo you don't need any `.git` in the destination folder `/var/www/project/`, since you are using the .git of your bare repo (`--git-dir`)

Comment: @Isengo I would not recommend yupengzhang's solution. The .git you have is made for a bare repo, and for pushing to it. A simple checkout is more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is get the .git from one cloned workcopy and copy .git to your var/www/project. As all the contents are the same, so the workspace is clean.

May this help you :P

Comment: That is what I thougt too, but I am afraid it will crash something live :-/