# How sort properties files by key during git push?

Tags: git, properties, githooks, properties-file

There is a git repository and some property files in it like that:

```
//application.properties
bKey=12345
aKey=myValue
```

After `git push` executed a remote git server should sort these files like that:

```
//application.properties
aKey=myValue
bKey=12345
```

How write hook for that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new custom alias in bashrc which would perform both git push and trigger your bash script (which will sort your properties file).

It's not exactly a hook but your problem can be solved by this way.

Edit: you can use pre-commit hook: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, a hook wxould not modify files.
But if your remote repo does checkout those files into a working tree (through a [post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41583600/6309) for instance, then you can associate to your remote git a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)** that would make that kind of transformation.

This assume you have access to the remote Git hosting server (meaning it is not GitHub.com or BitBucket.org or GitLab.com)

If that is the case, through a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309), you can declare a **`smudge`** script which would, for any `application.properties` file, make a sort of its content.

[image: smudge on checkout]

That would be done automatically on checkout.